# Azure Devops - Apply Variables Groups for pure Angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In ASP.NET MVC application, I can replace the web.config values with the value coming from Variable Group in Azure DevOps when deploying our codes to the live host

Is there a way I can do the same for application that only consist of only Angular scripts?

I know there is environment.ts file that can be used for replacing the configuration by environments

but I am hoping to use the Variable Groups in Azure DevOps as it's more convenient for us to use when we deploy our codes to the live host.

Comment: It's a bad practice to store application configuration in your continuous delivery provider. It tightly couples your application to a deployment tool and limits your ability to test locally or migrate to different solutions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Token Replacement extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to replace settings inside `environment.ts` file. It could look like this:

```
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@4
  inputs:
    targetFiles: 'environments/*.ts'
    encoding: 'auto'
    tokenPattern: 'default'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
    enableTransforms: false
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true
```

And then you should put token in env file to be replaced

```
export const environment = {
  production: #{VARIABLE_TO_BE_REPLACED}#
};
```

However, as Daniel already mentioned it will result in coupling with Azure Devops.